# Unable to share a link on whatsapp from Safari

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, share, whatsapp

I am trying to share a link from html on whatsapp using
 `<a href="whatsapp://send?text=title http://www.example.com">SHARE</a>`

This works fine for all browsers except safari.
In safari , When the share link is present on `www.example.com(I am trying to share the link of the page I am standing on)` page,if I try to share the link, only `title` text is shared, the link is not shared.

The whats app message generated is
`title`
despite of `title http://www.example.com`

Comment: I'm surprised Whatsapp doesn't handle this correctly. Calls to `http://api.whatsapp.com/?send...` redirect to `whatsapp://` - even if the browser doesn't recognise the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the text parameter using encodeURIComponent.

In your case that would be:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=title%20http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com">SHARE</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

We usually differ link at desktop view and mobile view to offer better support for safari and other browser.
for desktop view we use
    https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=6200000000&text=Hello%20Moxqitto

for mobile, we follow whatsapp best practice https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/
    https://wa.me/6200000000

Tested on 
Chrome for mac
safari for mac
android chrome

Ps: not tested when mac have whatsapp desktop app, but it will still work in the safari itself. so it should be ok